# Spring Boot 2 static resources subfolder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, staticresource

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.1.2, trying to get webservices and MVC working. Right now I have a directory structure like this:

[image: File tree]

Whenever I try to access `localhost:8080/findme.css` it resolves, but when I go to `localhost:8080/css/main.css` I get a 404.

I have tried messing around with `WebMvcConfigurer`'s `addResourceHandlers` method, but haven't had any luck. I've tried more combination's than whats pictured, but none seem to work.

[image: WebMvcConfigurer]

**How do I get resources in subfolders to be served?**

Just to add some more possibly relevant information, I'm running Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2018.3.  I'm starting the server by debugging the main function pictured here (at the root my my project). I'm also using gradle, not maven.
[image]

**Edit:**

So it seems Intellij has something to do with it. If I run `bootJar` and run the resulting `.jar` in `project/build/libs` it starts up and I can access `localhost:8080/css/main.css`. I'm not sure why it won't work with Intellij's run configuration so far.

Comment: The `resources` in `src/main/resources` isn't part of the `resourceLocation`; remove it.

Comment: Meaning I should be doing `registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**") .addResourceLocations("/static/css/")`, and should be able to access it from `localhost:8080/resources/main.css`?